# How to increase the distance between points in ggerrorplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

How can I increase the size between those points as they overlap right now and you cannot see certain groups?

Subset of data:

```
                    Species Transect Abundance Habitat
1 Camponotus novogradiensis T1       0         Torre
2 Nylanderia steinheili     T1       0         Torre
3 Paratrechina longicornis  T1       1         Torre
4 Azteca ACG6526            T1       3         Torre
5 Tapinoma ramulorum        T1       0         Torre
6 Dolichoderus curvilobus   T1       5         Torre
```

```
library(ggpubr)

ggerrorplot(data.2, x = "Species", y = "Abundance",
color = "Habitat",
error.plot = "pointrange",
orientation = "horizontal",
position = position_dodge(width=0))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share an example of your `data.2`? try editing your question to include the output of `dput(data.2)`

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot of my data

Comment: Thanks Marta, unfortunately screenshots of data are discouraged [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - could you please edit your question to include reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the argument in `position_dodge()` to some value greater than 0, maybe to `width = 0.5`